# Getting the data target's value dynamically fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get data target dynamically by using class method. The reason why I am doing this because I've currently have a working code snippet which I would like to refactor . My working JS code looks like this:

```
if ($('#i10').is(':checked')) {

    tot += parseInt($('#i10').val()) * parseInt($('#window10').val()) || 0;
}
if ($('#i11').is(':checked')) {

    tot += parseInt($('#i11').val()) * parseInt($('#window11').val()) || 0;
}
if ($('#i12').is(':checked')) {

    tot += parseInt($('#i12').val()) * parseInt($('#window12').val()) || 0;
}
if ($('#i13').is(':checked')) {

    tot += parseInt($('#i13').val()) * parseInt($('#window13').val()) || 0;
}
```

HTML example:

```
<input id="i10" class="checkbox-countable" type="checkbox" data-target='#window10' value="18 Yes">
<input type="number"  id="window10">
```

How I have tried to refactor my code:

```
if ($('.checkbox-countable').is(':checked')) {

    var target = $(this).data("target");
    tot += parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt(target.val()) || 0;
}
```

But i gent an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined"

Any suggestions how to resolve this or where possibly I have made a mistake?

**EDIT**: i am running this on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calculate").click(function() {
            if ($('.checkbox-countable').is(':checked')) {

                var target = $(this).data("target");
                tot += parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt(target.val()) || 0;
            }

        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
 <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Under what event are you running the code? What does `this` refer to?

Comment: Which event you are using..to execute this

Comment: `$('.checkbox-countable').change(fn);` and `$('.checkbox-countable:checked').each(fn)`...will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is because `this` will refer to the `#calculate` element as an `if` statement does not change the scope - functions do. To fix this you need to select the element and work with that jQuery object directly. Also, you need to wrap the `target` variable in a jQuery object. Right now `target` is a string, hence the error you're seeing. Try this:

```
$("#calculate").click(function () {
  $('.checkbox-countable:checked').each(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $target = $($checkbox.data("target"));
    tot += (parseInt($checkbox.val(), 10) * parseInt($target.val())) || 0;
  });
});
```

Comment: Rory your code works, but only with the first element(for e.g. with #i10, but not with #i11, #i12....) . Also that is keeping in mind if you add .val() to $checkbox

Comment: My original code was assuming you only had one checkbox. You'll need to loop if there's more than one. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this works. Not sure which one to select as the correct answer, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if this code supports your question please. Looks promising to me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calculate").click(function() {
    var tot = 0;
    $(':input[type="number"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != 0) {
        if ($("[data-target='#" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").is(':checked')) {
          var target = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
          var sub = parseInt(parseInt($("[data-target='" + target + "']").val())) * parseInt($(target).val()) || 0;
          tot += sub;
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(tot);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i11" class="checkbox-countable" type="checkbox" data-target='#window10' value="18 Yes">

<input type="number" id="window10">

<input id="i10" class="checkbox-countable" type="checkbox" data-target='#window11' value="19 Yes">

<input type="number" id="window11">

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

**Changes**:
Supports multiple checkbox selection + intelligent checkbox detection.

Comment: Your calculator is not valid. If you input 10 you get 10 . 10*10 , but it  should do for e.g. #i11 value * inputed number  and should be 18*10 =180 if the number is 10. Also, keep in mind that solutions has to work with multiple inputs as declared in the question - not just one.

Comment: Take a look at the code now please. Will do a generic version very soon.

Comment: It now does the task with one input, but why are using the regex for number matches ? The html input with type="number" solves the need for that. Haven't tried it with my original code which has multiple inputs, but probably won't try, because I've already found a working solution which seems efficient and clean to me. Inuka, I appreciate the effort, though

Comment: @Mkey implemented what Rory suggested. You're very welcome to try it.

Comment: One little draw back is even you haven't checked the second checkbox, it takes the value inside the `<input>` tag. Will rectify soon.

Comment: I can confirm now, that this solves my problem also, but not sure which of all the 3 answers I am going to mark as the correct one, because all of them solves the problem. Thanks! EDIT: yeah the second input checkbox should be fixed :)

Comment: @Mkey Check my revision now. I've updated the code. Now there is **no drawback.**

Answer (score 0):

Rory, your notice that my 'this" was referring not to the element I needed(because if doesn't changes the scope, but function does) helped me to come up with the correct answer:

```
   $('.checkbox-countable').each(function(){
                    if ($('.checkbox-countable').is(':checked')) {

                        var target = $(this).data("target");
                        tot += parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(target).val()) || 0;
                    }
                });
```